# Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/api' in 'D:\opensource\sound-redux\node_modules\soundcloud'

Tags: reactjs, redux

I try to create a soundcloud app and I received this error(ERROR in ./node_modules/soundcloud/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/api' in 'D:\opensource\sound-redux\node_modules\soundcloud') See the below image

[image]

I installed the module npm i --save soundcloud (see the image).

Also, I attached the ApiUtils.js file where I initiate the module(see the code).

```html
/* global fetch */
/* global window */
import camelize from 'camelize';
import SC from 'soundcloud';

export const callApi = (url, options) =>
  fetch(url, options)
    .then(
      response => (response.ok
        ? response.json()
        : Promise.reject(response.text())
      ),
      error => Promise.reject(error))
    .then(
      json => ({ json: camelize(json) }),
      error => ({ error }))
    .catch(error => ({ error }));

export const loginToSoundCloud = (clientId) => {
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: clientId,
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/api/callback`,
  });

  return SC.connect()
    .then(
      json => ({ json: camelize(json) }),
      error => ({ error }),
    )
    .catch(error => ({ error }));
};
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the library itself, you can post your question on the library repo

Comment: Can I send you the github url of the project?

Comment: Sure if you don't mind

Comment: https://github.com/andreighervan/sound-redux

Comment: Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After small research, it seems like the problem is in library (v3.3.1). The best option now is to stick with version v3.3.0 for now (seems workable from npm):

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "soundcloud": "3.3.0"
  ...
}
```

Or, build `soundcloud` lib locally.

Also, there's the issue described in the package repo on GitHub:
https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/49

And new issue for this problem in v3.3.1:
https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/93